# PhpStorm 8: Reset file type for a specific file

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

I created a file in PhpStorm 8, accidentally creating it without the ".php" extension, and now PhpStorm refuses to recognise it as a PHP file, or syntax highlight, autocomplete, etc, even after I changed the extension to .php...

I have tried deleting the file and recreating it, invalidating the cache through the File menu, deleting the .idea folder in the project, and deleting the whole project and pulling it from my Git server again, but PhpStorm still refuses to acknowledge it as a PHP file, even after multiple attempts to create it with the .PHP extension first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | File Types | Text files**

Find and remove unwanted pattern there

Comment: Life saver thank you! For some reason I initially checked under the PHP list rather than the text files list.